# Magento - Javascript: update form from user's choice

Tags: javascript, forms, magento

I'm writing a form for a custom module and I want to show/hide some fields according to which radio is checked, kind of like what happens when you select a payment method in the onepage checkout and a description appears.
Before I start writing the js code, I took a look at js/varien/form.js to see if I could use an already existing function, but the truth is my js skills aren't enough to really understand what I'm looking at.

So my question is, is there something I can use? Which method and how can I trigger it?
I'm gonna review onepage checkout's code in order to see if it makes things clearer, but if you know another form that has this behaviour please let me know.
Also, I know how I could write such code in plain javascript, but I'd rather use the magento way, in order to learn.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Javascript code doing is defined in `[skin]/js/opcheckout.js`. The Payment class defined there is made solely for the credit card checkout form.

You can study what they did and do something similar - or just write the show/hide code yourself. I'd suggest the latter if you don't have an insane amount of programmic logic - otherwise wrap it in a class.

Comment: ok, I see it, thx Janus. I'm going to study it and try to reproduce it, see if I can learn something.

Comment: well I've followed your advice, and wrote the show/hide code. One day I'll look into that matter, when I'll have some time...